# Running chunks based on output in RMarkdown

Tags: latex, rstudio, r-markdown, pandoc

I have a large document that I must compile in both pdf and docx. As a way of unifying both output I wanted to know if it is possible to run code based on the output selected. I have made the smallest reproducible example I could come with.

````
---
title: MyTest
output:
  word_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    toc: no
  pdf_document:
    latex_engine: xelatex
---


```{r setup_docx, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
library(captioner)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.path = 'images/',
                      echo = FALSE, 
                      warning = FALSE, 
                      message = FALSE,
                      include = TRUE)
```


# In Office Word the following is required

```{r figs, include=FALSE}
# Figures Required for Word Output
fig_nums <- captioner()
fig_nums("AppleFig", "This is the caption of my AppleFig")
```

These can be seen in `r fig_nums("AppleFig",display="cite")`


```{r, fig.cap=fig_nums("AppleFig")}
knitr::include_graphics("images/AppleFig.png")
```



```{r setup_pdf, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(fig.align='center',
                      fig.pos = 'H',
                      fig.path = 'images/',
                      echo = FALSE, 
                      warning = FALSE, 
                      message = FALSE,
                      include = TRUE,
                      out.width=".9\\textwidth")
```

# For LATEX

These can be seen in \ref{fig:AppleFig}

```{r, fig.cap="\\label{fig:AppleFig}This is the caption of my AppleFig."}
knitr::include_graphics("images/AppleFig.png")
```
````

[image: img]

[image: img]

At the moment I have 2 documents running each part of the code. Is there a way for me to select which chunks are run based on the output?

If this were possible my next step would be to try and run a Find+Replace for 
`ref\{figs:` to `fig_nums("`

Curious to get some input from the forum, I think it would be very useful for many people if it is possible to get done.

Comment: With `if(knitr::is_latex_output()){...}` you can execute code only when producing a LaTeX document.

Comment: Thanks this worked perfectly!